# HP Compaq Laptop freezing on boot

Tags: boot, laptop, freeze, touchpad, lubuntu

I build this notebook (HP Compaq nx6110) using two old notebooks plus a new HDD. This boot problem, also freezing / unfreezing situation is documented in several communities, including HP support forum. I have eliminated some usual factors that can halt processing, there was a connection problem with HDD and other minor issues. Now I have installed Lubuntu 17.10 that is running fast and smooth.

When I turn on the Laptop, it freezes in the boot screen with a big HP. To unfreeze it, I have to twist the console a bit or (what seems to be more efficient) press on the left side of the touchpad. Most of the times, it will freeze again during Lubuntu initialization, so I will press again on the left side and system unfreezes again. After finish initialization, Lubuntu seems to run ok, temperature ok, etc. a normal Laptop.

I tried to change the cover with the touchpad several times. With the replacement I have, the Laptop didn't freeze, but the buttons are not working either, not an option but give me the clue that the touchpad can be the problem - need to be sure before buying a new one.

Lubuntu runs really better than Windows, but I don't know much of Linux. I can see there is some messages soon after unfreezes, I could read "something wrong" but I could not keep the details. I don't know how to boot keeping a report, though will be really useful.

How can I correctly diagnose the source of the problem? Is there some other factors I should consider?

EDIT: upgraded to Lubuntu 18

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has a hardware fault and needs service by a competent technician.

Comment: Most likely, but not necessarily...

Comment: We are SuperUsers, we don't cry...